# Como quito las comillas a un string que contiene lo siguiente "2,3" ya que solo quiero que sea 2,3 para de esa manera ponerlo en una consulta sql

Tags: php, sql, laravel

la consulta listas me trae los amigos que tiene mi usuario y como la tabla listas contiene el solicitador y solicitante para ello lo que hago es quitar los id que sean igual a mi id autentificado para que de esa manera tener solo los id de mis amigos

Esto lo hago por que quiero mostrar los posts de mis amigos y para ello hago al final una consulta de tipo where in con el fin de mostrar solo los id de mis amigos

El problema es que decidi armar la query y para ello necesitaba tener los id separados por una coma, lo hice el resultado final no fue tal como lo esperaba ya que si bien logre que se mostraran los id de mis amigos y los separe por comas estos se muestran asi "2,3" y eso al ponerlo en la consulta de posts queda asi

laravel:

$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', [$output])->get();

sql:

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN ("2,3")

y bueno no funciona la consulta ya que deberia ser asi

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (2,3)

El codigo es el siguiente (Esta hecho con Laravel y es la parte del controlador)

```
public function index()
{
    $activo = Auth::user()->id;
    $listas = Lista::where('solicitador', $activo)
    ->where('status', '1')
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('solicitante', Auth::user()->id)
              ->where('status', '1');
    })
    ->get();
    $array = $listas->toArray();

    $result = [];

    foreach($array as $item) {
        if($item['solicitador'] != $activo) {
            $result[] = $item['solicitador'];
        }
        if($item['solicitante'] != $activo) {
            $result[] = $item['solicitante'];
        }
    }
    
    $output = "";

    foreach($result as $item) {
        $output .= $item.',';
    }

    $output = rtrim($output, ",");
    dd($output); //esto me da como resultado "2,3"

    if($output != "") {
        $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', [$output])->get();
        return view('home.posts.index', compact('posts', 'listas'));
    }
    return view('home.posts.index', compact('listas'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario que conviertas el `array` a `string`, ya que con `whereIn` solo necesitas pasarle un `array` con los valores que buscas, por lo que hay muchas cosas que son innecesarias en el código, y para validar que hay datos dentro del `array` solo verifica que no este vacío, quedaría así:

```
public function index()
{
    $activo = Auth::user()->id;
    $listas = Lista::where([['solicitador', $activo], ['status', '1']])
    ->orWhere([['solicitante', $activo], ['status', '1']])
    ->get();

    $i=0;
    $result = [];

    foreach($listas as $item) {
        if($item->solicitador != $activo) {
            $result[$i] = $item->solicitador;
            $i++;
        }
        if($item->solicitante != $activo) {
            $result[$i] = $item->solicitante;
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if(!empty($result) && isset($result[0])) {
        $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $result)->get();
        return view('home.posts.index', compact('posts', 'listas'));
    }
    return view('home.posts.index', compact('listas'));
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: De nada @MauroPoloni :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el segundo parámetro del `whereIn()` debería ser un array con los distintos valores que le quieras pasar, pero tú estás declarando un array con un único valor (`$output`), que únicamente contiene un valor (la cadena `2,3`). Corrigiendo eso, debería funcionar:

```
public function index()
{
    /* .. */
    
    $output = [];

    foreach ($result as $item) {
        $output[] = $item;
    }

    if ( ! empty($output)) {
        $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $output)->get();
        return view('home.posts.index', compact('posts', 'listas'));
    }

    /* .. */
}
```